# Add new lines while concating multiple files

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I have a folder with tables as sub-folders which contain one stored procedure. To concat those I do this:

```
for /r %i in (*) do type "%i" >> concat.sql
```

But I need to add a couple of new lines after each .sql file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answering my own question, in case someone lands upon this post.

I did this and it worked:

```
for /r %i in (*) do type "%i" >> concat.sql & echo. >> concat.sql
```

Seems I need to concat the output file and new line(echo.) in every loop.